# Swift 3 with Sqlite: "Use of unresolved identifier 'Database'"

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, ipad, swift3

I want to read database from my sqlite but I got the error. I try to find many solution but can't help.

Please help me.

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "sqlite")!
    let db = Database(path, readonly: true)
    var cities : [String]?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for row in db.prepare("SELECT name FROM engcate") {
            print("row \(row[0] as! String)")
            cities!.append(row[0] as! String)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Its look like **Database** is one type of swift class. From where you integrated this?

Comment: I think it is in sqlite.swift library. I follow from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232081/swift-how-to-populate-uitableview-with-sqlite-column

Comment: I checked the _SQLite.swift_ there is no **Database** keyword is there. And according to the documentation you have to use `let db = try Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")` to initialize a db. Or you can create a **Database.swift** class where you can define these code and call like you mentioned in your code.